# Multiple Gstreamer Pipelines Running Simultaneously

Tags: python, gstreamer, pipeline, rtsp

I'm new to Gstreamer and trying to find an efficient way to perform two rtsp streamings simultaneously. The way I'm currently doing is by defining two separate pipelines inside my Python script and run them via cv2.VideoCapture(). When I run single pipeline everything works great, however when two pipelines are running, I get a few seconds of latency which I cannot tolerate. I know there must be a more efficient way of doing this so really appreciate if someone helped me out.

For clarity, my code for single pipeline looks something like this:

`gst1 = 'rtspsrc location=rtspt://my.rtsp.link ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder enable-max-performance=1 ! nvvidconv ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink sync=false'`

`cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(gst1, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)`
Followed by a while loop which reads the frames etc. I have two of these for streaming two IP cameras and it clearly slows down the stream. My goal is to show them inside a single frame (picture-in-picture) that's why I cannot use such pipelines that open two separate windows. I must have two pipelines and two capture objects for cv2.VideoCapture() and a single frame. I hope I made it clear enough.

Thanks in advance for any help!